# enotez loses an endnote placed in a figure caption when using endfloats

Tags: captions, endfloat, enotez

My MWE is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
\endnote{First endnote}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Hi! \endnote{Second endnote}}
\end{figure}
\endnote{Third endnote}
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the list of notes, the second endnote is missing, without any warning or error message. I am certainly okay with reduced functionality in this edge case, but I wonder if the fact that this happens without notifying the user is intended/known or considered a bug.

Edit: reducing the MWE to be independent of `endfloat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
  \endnote{Good endnote}
  \printendnotes
  \endnote{Missing endnote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This indeed looks like a bug. If you want you can file an issue at https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez/issues.

Comment: @Marijn done: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez/issues/20/enotez-loses-an-endnote-placed-in-a-figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify `\printendnotes`, it turns off the automatic print `\AtEndDocument`.  So the `\endnote` in the caption is executed too late.  Also, you will get two endnotes (3 and 4) if you do not specify a short caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
\endnote{First endnote}
\begin{figure}
    \caption[Hi!]{Hi! \endnote{Second endnote}}
\end{figure}
\endnote{Third endnote}
\processdelayedfloats
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

---

If you want the endnotes to appear before the endfloats, one can use saveboxes (one for each figure containing an endnote).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\usepackage{enotez}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]% #1 = figure or table
{\def\@captype{#1}}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\figureA}

\begin{document}
\endnote{First endnote}

\savebox{\figureA}{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
  \setcaptype{figure}% or use \captionof from caption or capt-of packages
  \caption[Hi!]{Hi! \endnote{Second endnote}}
\end{minipage}}%
\begin{figure}
  \usebox\figureA
\end{figure}

\endnote{Third endnote}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer with a useful workaround, but I still feel that endnotes should not go missing without warning message. `enotez` should know that at the end of the document, some endnotes have not been printed yet. I can even imagine that `enotez` would be able to write all endnotes into an aux file and read from there during the next run.

Comment: Interesting - I do not see an `.ent` file anywhere near my `aux` directory.

Comment: Oops. .ent is created by endotes, not enotez.  Enotez uses the aux file.  No idea why it doesn't use both.  Counter?

Comment: It seems that \printendnotes deliberately does not print notes which have not been written yet.  OTOH, you can call \printendnotes more than once and each time it will only print the new notes.  Alas, it was written in expl3 which i cannot read.